# Unable to produce graph with grViz directly from a source file

Tags: r

I try to use the DiagrammeR package (http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/) for producing automatic graphs in R.

I was able to create graphs in Rgui in interactive mode for example by typing :

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("digraph {A -> B}")
```

In that way, a new tab opens in Firefox and shows the graph.

Now, if I put this code in a test.R file and if I call this file from Rgui or with Rscript.exe by typing `source("test.R")` nothing happened.

I'm on windows 7 - 64bits, and i used R portable (http://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/).

Comment: add `print(grViz("digraph {A -> B}"))`

Comment: Thanks @user20650 ! It works in Rgui but i'm still unable to make it works with Rscript

Comment: Im not actually familiar with DiuagrammeR, so how about actually calling `graphviz` via the `shell` and using this to render and output a pdf / png . jpeg....Its not much extra work.

Comment: My R script could generate a gv file and since GraphViz is a portable application, so I could copy it in a folder and run dot.exe from R. This will burdening installation for end users but this is an option. Too bad for DiagrammeR that appeared to be promising :(

Comment: There must be a way. to export the graphs to more devices, but i cant see it in the docs.  `cat(exportSVG(grViz("digraph {A -> B}")), file="output.svg")` for an `svg` image

Answer (score 3):

Big thanks to @user20650 that gives all the solutions :

If running script from Rgui, one should type `print(grViz("digraph {A -> B}"))` for having the graph displayed in the web-browser.

Running the script from Rscript needs to export the graph under another format. It can be exported as SVG file using "V8" package by typing :

```
cat(exportSVG(grViz("digraph {A -> B}")), file='ouput.svg')
```